# Xcopy equivlent for VB.net

Tags: vb.net, move, xcopy

Simple question how do i copy and move the entier contents of a directory to another ussing VB.net then also delete the files from there original directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the easiest way:

```
FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(sourceFolder, outputFolder)
FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(sourceFolder, FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)
```

There are additional overloads with a few more options, like showing dialogs to the user during copy.